# Tell wget not to spider URL matching a pattern?

Tags: wget, url

I want to test how my site would be behave when being spidered. However, I want to exclude all URLs containing the word "page". I tried:

```
$ wget -r -R "*page*" --spider --no-check-certificate -w 1 http://mysite.com/
```

The `-R` flag is supposed to reject URL pattern containing the word "page". Except that it doesn't seem to work:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2014-06-10 12:34:56--  http://mysite.com/?sort=post&page=87729
Reusing existing connection to [mysite.com]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

How do I exclude spidering of such URL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some trial and error, I realise the solution is simply to use `--reject-regex` like this:

```
wget -r --reject-regex page --spider --no-check-certificate -w 1 http://mysite.com/
```

The urlregex must not contain wildcard and hence `*page*` is invalid, but `page` is.

Comment: Thanks! After many trial and errors it worked! I'm curious how it would be to add more words to reject together?

Answer (score 2):

From `man wget`:

```
-R rejlist --reject rejlist
           Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
           accept or reject.
```

This option will only reject **files** that match the pattern.

Strictly speaking, in your URL `page` is a request parameter, not the last part of the path (e.g. file name).

---

You might want to dump all URLs that wget found (e.g. grep the log for all downloaded URLs), remove those URLs that do not satisfy you (with grep -v, for example) and finally make wget retrieve the URLs left. For example:

```
# dump the whole website
wget ... -P dump -o wget.log  ...

# extract URLs from the log file
cat wget.log | grep http | tr -s " " "\012" | grep http >urls

# excludes URLs with the word page anywhere in it
cat urls | grep -v page >urls 

# delete previous dump, since it probably contains unwanted files
rm -rf dump

# Fetch URLs
cat urls | xargs wget -x
```

You might want to add other wget options (e.g. --no-check-certificate) according to your needs.

Comment: I did read the manual a few times. As you can see, it says "file name suffixes _or_ patterns", so it isn't that clear if the pattern must be a file name. Nevertheless, I am looking for a solution that allows exclusion of a specific URL pattern.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow See the edit for one example of how you might do it.

Comment: Your second option would spider the entire site, downloading everything. Then it would download almost everything a second time. It would be more efficient to download everything and then delete the parts that don't satisfy you.